# ¿Por qué los spinners no funcionan en smartphone?

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

Buenas a todos!

Estoy desarrollando una App móvil que tiene 3 spinners, el problema es que en el emulador la App trabaja perfectamente pero cuando la instalo en teléfonos reales no funcionan los spinners, no muestran el contenido.

La instale en un samsung galaxy S3 y funciona perfectamente también, si instalo en otros modelos no funciona bien. No se si el problema se por el nivel de API o algo por el estilo, he buscado en un mundo de foros y no encuentro una respuesta valida.

El código esta bien porque lo he revisado y ademas funciona excelente en el emulador de Geny Motion. Aquí les dejo dos imágenes una del emulador y otra del teléfono móvil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Búsqueda de Medicos"
                            android:textSize="25dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:background="#448AFF" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tViewProvincias"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Provincias"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerProvincias"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tViewCentroSalud"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Centros de Salud"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerCentroSalud"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tViewEspecialidad"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Especialidades"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerEspecialidad"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            />


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnBuscarMedico"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Buscar"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                </ScrollView>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lViewMedicosTurnos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


             </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lViewCitas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Esto me sale en el android monitor cuando ocurre el error.

```
04-26 23:15:22.161 18483-19357/turno.mi.angelgrullon.miturno D/Respuesta: 
The response is: 200
04-26 23:15:22.181 18483-19366/turno.mi.angelgrullon.miturno I/System.out: 
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-26 23:15:22.261 18483-18483/turno.mi.angelgrullon.miturno 
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
04-26 23:15:22.301 18483-18483/turno.mi.angelgrullon.miturno W/System.err: 
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 500000 of 
[{"IdProvincia":"1","Nombre":"Distrito Nacional, Santo Domingo"},
{"IdProvincia":"2","Nombre":"La Altagracia, Salvale\u00f3n de Hig\u00fcey"},
{"IdProvincia":"3","Nombre":"Azua, Azua de Compostela"},
{"IdProvincia":"4","Nombre":"Bahoruco, Neiba"},
{"IdProvincia":"5","Nombre":"Barahona, Santa Cruz de Barahona"}
```

{"IdProvincia":"����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

Comment: creo que si funcionan, lo que pasa es que están muy en el limite de la pantalla(no se detecta el evento touch del spinner), si le das un margin derecho y pruebas de nuevo lo comprobarás

Comment: Aun nada Rene Limon, agregue el margen derecho y no funciona, revise el tamaño de la fuente y algunos detalles mas y nada.

Comment: @AngelGrullon agrega tu layout por favor.

Comment: Ahí esta el layout @Jorgesys.

Comment: El problema comenzó después de actualizar el android studio a la versión 2.3